# Generalized likelihood ratio test for known means and unknown variance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, likelihood-ratio, composite

Consider a sequence, $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$, of independent random variables. I have two hypotheses:

$H_0 : X_k \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_0, \sigma^2), k=1,2,\dots,n$

$H_1 : X_k \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \sigma^2), k=1,2,\dots,n$

where $\mu_0, \mu_1$ are both known (pretend they are 0 and 1, as an example), and $\sigma^2 > 0$ is unknown. Thus, our likelihood under $H_i$ is given by

$\begin{equation}f(Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_n|H_i) = (\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2})^\frac{n}{2}\prod_{k=1}^ne^{-\frac{(x_k - \mu_i)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\end{equation} \quad (1)$

My confusion comes from the fact that the variance doesn't exist in two separate sets, $\Theta_0$ and $\Theta_1$. Based on the problem definition, it would seem that the variance is in the same set of all positive real numbers for both hypotheses. I understand that the goal is to find the maximizing variance under each hypothesis and then use that in the desired ratio, however I am feeling a bit lost. Is this as simple as taking the derivative of $(1)$ and solving for $\sigma$ under each hypothesis? I was under the impression that for the generalized likelihood ratio test the unknown parameter needed to be in distinct sets for each hypothesis.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the variance doesn't exist in two separate sets"?  The parameters of this problem are $(\mu,\sigma^2) \in \{\mu_0,\mu_1\}\times [0,\infty).$ You could depict this as two parallel (vertical) rays in the plane, if you like: one of them denotes $\Theta_0$ and the other denotes $\Theta_1.$  Unless $\mu_0=\mu_1,$ in this picture they are obviously disjoint.

Comment: I did not consider the sets that way. That makes much more sense - thank you. I suppose my question remains; to find that maximizing variance do I simply differentiate (1) w.r.t $\sigma$ and solve?

Comment: That's one way -- there are others, as taught in differential Calculus classes.  In the present case it's easier to maximize the logarithm.  You also need to inspect the boundaries of the sets.